# jQuery generated elements won't call function

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

i have generate anchore from ajax here is the code

```
  html+=' <a  class="btn-floating activator btn-move-up z-depth-4 modal-trigger right" href=".update-topic-modals" >'
                 html+='<i class="material-icons  blue-text text-darken-4 white" id="editmodal" onclick="editFunction('+value._id+');" >edit</i></a>'
```

when i click this anchore function: editFunction(value) is not calling
here is a editFunction() code

```
    <script>function editFunction(_id) {  alert(_id);      }</script>
```

here is how it looks like

[image: image of button that is generated by jQuery]

when im pressing this btn function is not calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make several changes

1. move the onclick
2. store the data in a data attribute
3. delegate the click
4. preventDefault on the click to not load the href

```js
function editFunction(_id) {
  console.log(_id);
}

var value = {
  _id: "hello"
}

html = '<a data-id="' + value._id + '" class="btn-floating activator btn-move-up z-depth-4 modal-trigger right" href=".update-topic-modals" >'
html += '<i class="material-icons  blue-text text-darken-4 white" id="editmodal">edit</i></a>'

$("#container").on("click",".modal-trigger",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  editFunction($(this).attr("data-id"));
});

$("#container").append(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: what if i want to send more data in data-id?

Comment: i have send these vars in data-id

     html += '<a data-id="' + value._id + ','+value.videoUrl+','+value.imgUrl+','+value.text+','+value.title+','+value.code+' " class="btn-floating activator btn-move-up z-depth-4 modal-trigger right" href=".update-topic-modals" >'

Comment: You can make more data attributes and pass `this` to the function. Or use a dataset

Comment: Pass a key to the value object instead